# xcode 7.2 instruments can't choose target(device greyed)

Tags: xcode, instruments

Just like this
[image]

[image]

have someone ever meet with this issue,please help ,thanks!

Comment: Is your device is configured for development (look at it inside Xcode organizer, devices)?

Comment: @RashwanL In Xcode7.2 there is no organizer -> devices,do you mean window->devices?

Comment: You´re right, I think they have removed it. But have you checked the deployment target? Go to Project Settings -> Info. Change the deployment target to a lower or higher version.

Comment: I just tried to change target to 8.0 and 9.2,both didn't work :( and my device is in apple developer center ->iOS devices list.I can still run my app in this device

Comment: And a computer reboot did not solve this?

Comment: failed... how could it be so weird Man:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I solved this by myself, for anyone who come after me, try to reboot your target device.

Comment: Did that to no avail. Then I also rebooted my Mac. That worked. I can't believe we've come to this.

Comment: @Surpher Before rebooting my device I also tried rebooting my mac for no avail :-)

Comment: Jozo.Yang I guess rebooting both did the job for both of us.

Answer (score 0):

Just disconnect the device worked for me.